# Ошибка. Сбой при загрузке  Сертификат, использованный для подписи APK-файла, ещё не действителен.

Tags: android, google-play

При загрузке приложения выдаёт такую ошибку

Сбой при загрузке

Сертификат, использованный для подписи APK-файла, ещё не действителен. Используйте действительный сертификат.

Дату на 1 день наза переводил - не помогло

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Закрывайте вопрос. Моя ошибка была в том, что я думал, что дату надо переводить и создавать приложение, а сертификат был создан ещё со старой датой (Не переведённой). Просто надо было перевести на 1 день назад и создать новый файл ключей, а потом уже подписывать им приложение.